# How does the kraken get its bait?

Tags: creature-design, sea-creatures, fishing

The kraken is a great sea monster, with many heads, pincers, and tentacles. Anatomically it is similar to a whale in most parts, but with crab-like features particularly in the pincers, as well as a few cephalopod traits

The important trait of my kraken is its feeding strategy: It produces a small amount of food from its mouth, as bait, which it uses to catch smaller fish

The precise qualities of the food are not important. The only criteria are that the food must be nutritrious, at least slightly, and be usable as bait for fish

What is the most efficient way for my kraken to create such a bait?

Comment: there are a thousand answers to this, with no criteria this a a textbook opinion based question.

Comment: @John How can there be a thousand equally efficient ways of making food?

Comment: Most efficient compared to what? All possible efficiencies would be off-topic (book rule). Efficient can refer to capture of food, storage of food, pre-digestion of food, what's used as food, what fish are attracted by the food, and quite a few more. Please identify the specific efficiencies we're to use to qualify our answers.

Comment: Further, please provide specific details concerning your kraken's physiology so we can identify efficiencies that relate to physiology. Size, weight, active-vs-resting times, location in the sea (long/lat), how many heads? Do the heads act independently? Can they act in concert? Do the heads feed one digestive system or multiple? Metabolism... We'll help you create your world, Ichthys, but we won't create it for you.

Comment: It has many heads, but the question is about its mouth, singular.  So, is the mouth part of one head, or nothing to do with the heads, or... Much more detail required - we don't even know how it catches the fish the bait is for, does it swim after them, suddenly close its tentacles around them, catch them in its pincers...? (how are the pincers attached?  are they on the tentacles?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Stuff it ate earlier.**

[image: orca uses bait to hunt birds]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14wWxaMR2Mg

Here an orca has regurgitated a fish for use in baiting birds.  I watched one do this probably at this exact spot.  In my video, when the bird did not take the bait the orca spit water on the bird.  That is not how it goes in this video.

Your kraken barfs up some chum.  Little fish come.  Bigger fish come.  Big fish come.  Kraken comes back to collect return on its investment.

Comment: I don't know what was more disturbing - the perfectly natural circle of life that leads an Orca to sucker a bird (of all things...) or the happy humans cheering the Orca. Either way, unless the kraken has a napsack, +1 for the only sensible way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a real world animal that does this simply and efficiently as possible.  The Alligator Snapping Turtle use it's tongue to imitate a wriggling pink worm that lures fish into striking distance of the predator.  No prior food required (although this is not the only method of procuring food the the Alligator Snapping Turtle as it will eat carrion and has been known to eat American Alligators.  Additionally, your creature has features that would make it ideal to take a similar strategy to the Mimic Octopus, which has been observed to mimic a wide variety of sea life both in defensive and aggressive situations.

Aggressive Mimicry is a strategy employed by any animal who adapts to luring prey by imitating a situation that entices its prey, while defensive mimicry is a strategy where imitating dangerous non-prey deters predators (such as some species of non-venomous snakes and butterflies which have colors that are similar to venomous snakes and butterflies.  One famous example is that of the Coral Snake.  It's distinct Red-Yellow-Black bands are imitated by two separate non-venomous species of snakes, both the Scarlet King Snake and several subspecies of the Milk Snake, which share a Red-Black-Yellow.  Those living in the Eastern United States, the home of these snakes, have a several poems to help remember which ones are safe and which are not (Red on Yellow, Kill a Fellow.  Redo on Black, Venom Lack/Friend of Jack).  Other Milk Snake sub-species have been killed by humans who mistake them for other venomous snakes, such as Pygmy Rattle Snakes or Copperheads, also found in these similar ranges in North America.